# Python pandas add a column with a value comparing columns with certain external sets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe (~30 000 rows) count of trips by station code.

| station from | station to | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20001 | 20040 | 55 |
| 20040 | 20001 | 67 |
| 20007 | 20080 | 100 |
| 20080 | 20007 | 50 |

and dataset - route id: list of station id. Example 10001 (20001,2020,20013, ... 20040); 10002 (20007,2000,20019, ... 20080). There are about 100 such routes.
The task is to get add the name of the route to the dataframe according to the criterion if the station of departure and destination is included in one or another set

| station from | station to | count | route |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20001 | 20040 | 55 | 1001 |
| 20040 | 20001 | 67 | 1001 |
| 20007 | 20080 | 100 | 1002 |
| 20080 | 20007 | 50 | 1002 |

In the primary form, the list of routes is an xml file (Sation id C1 item, route id NM),  I can parse it, but I don't know what form to convert it to (dataframe, dict) and what to do next

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?><MRS1>
<MR NM="002001" PT="0">
<C N="001" C1="2040484" L="000" NZ="099" PZ="0000" NO="01" S="ВЕР УФАЛЕЙ  " ZT="0" />
<C N="002" C1="2040751" L="006" NZ="099" PZ="0000" NO="01" S="ОП 100 КМ   " ZT="0" />
...
<C N="022" C1="2030055" L="106" NZ="099" PZ="0000" NO="07" S="ШАРТАШ      " ZT="0" />
<C N="023" C1="2031190" L="108" NZ="099" PZ="0000" NO="07" S="ПЕРВОМАЙСК  " ZT="0" />
<C N="024" C1="2030000" L="110" NZ="099" PZ="0000" NO="07" S="ЕКАТЕРИНБ П " ZT="0" />
</MR>
<MR NM="002002" PT="0">
<C N="001" C1="2040000" L="000" NZ="099" PZ="0000" NO="01" S="ЧЕЛЯБИНСК   " ZT="0" />
<C N="002" C1="2041748" L="002" NZ="099" PZ="0000" NO="01" S="ЛОКОМОТИВ1  " ZT="0" />
...
<C N="044" C1="2041502" L="152" NZ="099" PZ="0000" NO="01" S="ОП 1948 КМ  " ZT="0" />
<C N="045" C1="2040550" L="160" NZ="099" PZ="0000" NO="01" S="ЗЛАТОУСТ    " ZT="0" />
</MR>
<MRS1>
```

Comment: How are the routes stored? As dict? pls show a sample of route to station mapping.

Comment: Do routes have overlaps? if yes, how do you want to deal with them?

Comment: Yes, there may be matches in the routes, but I will get rid of them before comparing them, or just look for the first occurrence

Comment: I add sample xml of route

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say, you parse the XML and convert it into a dict format like below:

```
route_id = {1001 : [20001,20040], 1002: [20007,20080]}
```

Then, you write this piece of code to convert into a format which you can later use to do `series.map`.

```
route_rev = {}
for i,k in zip(route.keys(), route.values()):
    for j in k:
        route_rev[j] = i
print(route_rev)
{20001: 1001, 20040: 1001, 20007: 1002, 20080: 1002}
```

Now, simply use `map` and match the station code from `station_from`  to the corresponding route code from the `route_rev` dict.

```
df['route'] = df.station_from.map(route_rev)
print(df)
   station_from  station_to  count  route
0         20001       20040     55   1001
1         20040       20001     67   1001
2         20007       20080    100   1002
3         20080       20007     50   1002
```